# make [source directory cannot contain spaces or colons.] の対処方法が知りたい

Tags: linux, makefile

###### 質問内容

提示コンソール画面は以下のサイトからダウンロードしてきたLinuxのカーネルです。これをビルドしてISOファイルにしてvmware playerで実行したいのですが以下のエラーコードの対処方法がわかりません。

###### 知りたい事

`ソース ディレクトリにスペースやコロンを含めることはできません`と書いてあり参考サイトには`ソース ツリーを別の場所に移動する必要があります。`が対処方法として書いてありますがこれはどこに移動すればいいのでしょうか？また`ソースディレクトリにスペースやコロン`とありますがソースディレクトリとはどこのコードなのでしょうか？

###### google翻訳

```
source directory cannot contain spaces or colons
ソース ディレクトリにスペースやコロンを含めることはできません
```

###### 試したこと

ディレクトリをダウンロードディレクトリに移動して実行

###### 環境

OS: windows 10
gun make windows

###### コンソール

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19044.2251]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\XXX>cd C:\Users\XXX\Desktop\linux-6.0.12

C:\Users\XXX\Desktop\linux-6.0.12>make
makefile:191: *** source directory cannot contain spaces or colons.  中止.

C:\Users\XXX\Desktop\linux-6.0.12>
```

ダウンロードしてきたプロジェクト(Last release): https://www.kernel.org/
参考サイト(google翻訳)：https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/475757/why-wont-make-let-me-build-my-kernel-from-source

Comment: Windows のユーザー名が伏せられていますが、空白を含むユーザー名だったりしませんか？ / kernel 単体がコンパイルできても OS ではないので起動しませんし、Windows 環境でコンパイルしようとしているのも色々問題が出てくると思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます。そもそもlinuxで実行するものなのでしょうか？

Comment: Linux kernelは「カーネルコンフィグレーション」(設定)を行ないコンパイルします。その過程が必要だしそもそも Windowsではムリと思われます。ビルドができたら 通常はブート時に実行するものです

Comment: [Gentoo](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Handbook:AMD64/ja) を空いた PCにインストールしてみてはどうでしょう？ その過程でカーネルコンフィグも行うので

Comment: ありがとうございます。質問ですがその場合いつOSをコーディングするのでしょうか？

Comment: OSをコーディングとは？ Linuxデバイスドライバー作り方などは本が出てます。カーネルの機能追加などはまずカーネル知ることが先。OSに必要なソフトはコーディングするのではなくビルドする程度です

Comment: いや C:\ とコロンが含まれているぢゃん

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows上で(WSLやHyper-V上のLinux等の仮想環境を使用せずに)Linuxカーネルをコンパイルしたいと言うことで良いですね？

コロンが含まれないパスにするには、Cygwin版のmakeやMSYS2のビルド用make(makeパッケージ)等を使用する必要があります。[Make for Windows](https://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/make.htm)やMSYS2のmingw32-make(mingw-w64-*-make)ではWindowsのパスをそのまま使用するため、ドライブのパスにコロンが必ず含まれてしまいます。しかし、Cygwin版やMSYSのビルド用makeはUNIXライクな環境をエミュレートするため、UNIXライクなパスとして処理し、「C:\」は「/c/」となるなど、コロンを含めないパスにできます。

なお、それらのmakeを使用しただけでは、正常にコンパイルすることは出来ません。たとえば、Cygwinを使ってコンパイルするだけでも、下記記事に記載されている色々なことをする必要があります。
[Cygwin 上で Linux カーネルをクロスコンパイル - Qiita](https://qiita.com/shina/items/9f6e02cd5e504605850d)
レジストリでファイルシステムの動作を変えるところから始まって、クロスコンパイル用のGCCのコンパイルまで必要になってきます。記事通りにやっても、バージョンの違いでうまくいかない場合もあります。さらに、Cygwin以外になるとシンボリックの扱いの問題等も出てきてさらにハードルが高いでしょう。